# rails_admin: set a selected tab in a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm using rails_admin to make something like a slide show.

```
class SlideShow
  has_many :slides
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :slides,  allow_destroy: true
end
```

Etc.

And one request I get from my users is this: They'll be working on the third slide in a slideshow. They will hit "save and edit" and they'll get bounced back to the first slide in the nested form.

Does anyone know of a way to open them to the third slide after saving?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

**1) Session Variable:**

Create a session variable and set the id of the last active slide, pass it between your controller actions and use it to take the user back to that slide, once you save a slide.

**2) Getters & Setters:**

Create helper methods:

```
def last_active_slide=(id)
   @slide_id = id
 end

def last_active_slide
  @slide_id
end
```

Call the setter when storing the last active slide id and the getter to retrieve the id to take the user back to that slide.

Comment: Right. I mean, I know the general approach. The Question si really how to hack it together without totally gutting rails_admin